# Как исправить ошибку «Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null»?

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в JS и не знаю в чём ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```
document.body.onload = function()
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        var preloader = document.getElementById('load');
        if ( !preloader.classList.contains('done') ){
            preloader.classList.add('done');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: На странице нет элемента с id "load".

Comment: @user299226, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение означает, что на странице нет элемента с `id="load"`. Вот так правильно:

```js
document.body.onload = function()
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        var preloader = document.getElementById('load');
        if ( !preloader.classList.contains('done') ){
            preloader.classList.add('done');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.done{color: green}
```

```html
<div id="load"><b>Страница полностью загружена.</b></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать свойство документа `body`

```
var preloader = document.body;
```

Думаю, что вы это хотели получить с помощью `document.getElementById('load');`, но такого элемента с `id="load"` нет на странице.